# Open existing report from Google Analytics GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am developing an api to get data from Google Analytics.

Is there any way that I can open an existing Google Analytics report (GA4) using an http request, Java or Python?

I was trying this documentation,
[Google analytics data api run report](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport)

It is great to create the report from scratch, but I want to open an existing report

from the browser of the web console of google analytics, I can see this URL for my report:

```
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=9#/analysis/pABCDEFGH/edit/VLE12345678901_765432 (I changed the ids)
```

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to stack please watch your tagging only use tags relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport) and in fact all google apis return raw data in the form of Json.

What you are looking for is not possible via this api, or any api currently.   If you take the exact dimensions, metrics and dates you can make the same request to the report your self.

There by recreating the data behind the existing report.

I suspect what you are looking for is something like the [Google analytics embedded api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1) this was originally created for the Google analytics core reporting api and works only with UA analytics.

I have asked the team and currently and was told there are currently no plans to port it for use with GA4